# Reading chars within a string to output only vowels in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to take a user entered string, cycle through each char within the string, and then print only the vowels.

I've posted below what I have so far, but of course all it does is output the first char from the string, regardless of whether or not it's a vowel (just FYI, this is for a class, so I'm not looking for someone to give me the answer, but I definitely need some guidance!)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string userString;
    char vowels = ('a','e','i','o','u');
    char stringArr = userString[0];

    cout << "Enter some text: ";
    cin >> userString;
    cout << endl;

    if (stringArr == 'a'|'e'|'i'|'o'|'u')
        cout << userString[0] << " " << endl << endl;
    else
        cout << "No vowels found.";

return 0;
}
```

Comment: This isn't *invalid* syntax, but it's completely incorrect and doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: You cannot combine things in `if` like that. Your `vowels` also doesn't do what you think it does. Check arrays in any book.

Comment: `const char vowels[] = {'a','e','i','o','u'};` and use a loop.

Comment: `char vowels = ('a','e','i','o','u');`: you might want to look up the comma operator, it's playing a trick on you here. Similarly, in `stringArr == 'a'|'e'|'i'|'o'|'u'` you're using the bitwise and operator, which is also not doing what you want.

Comment: If this is for a class, then you should've received some sort of introduction to C++. Re-read that again! Additionally, get a book / online tutorial on C++. This is far from working code.

Comment: guidance: try to use a `switch` statement with fall through instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, your array declaration syntax is incorrect.

Since you are using C++, you should be using the built-in [`array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) class for static (fixed-length) arrays.

The correct way to initialize an array is with the following syntax:

```
std::array<char, 5> vowels = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
```

Next, this syntax is also not doing what you think it is:

```
if (stringArr == 'a'|'e'|'i'|'o'|'u')
```

The `|` is actually a binary or, meaning it's doing bit manipulation, which isn't what you want. Also, it's odd that you declare the vowels and then re-state all the vowels in this if statement. *Don't repeat yourself!* Use the list you already made and search that. It makes your code much easier to maintain.

The standard way to search an `array` (and many other container classes) is to use the `find` function.

```
c = 'a'; // some character
find(vowels.begin(), vowels.end(), c) != vowels.end()
```

What this means is that it will return `true` if `c` is found in `vowels`.

So now we just need to go through *all* the characters of the string the user entered. In order to do this you need to use a loop. In C++, there is something called a [range-based `for` loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for). The syntax is as follows:

```
for (auto c : user_string)
{
    // do something with c
}
```

This will iterate through the entirety of the string, and execute the code inside the block (`{ }`) for each character.

Here is working code that does exactly what you want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool vowels_found = false;
    string user_string = "yea man";
    array<char, 5> vowels = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };

    for (auto c : user_string)
    {
        if (find(vowels.begin(), vowels.end(), c) != vowels.end())
        {
            cout << c;

            vowels_found = true;
        }
    }

    if (!vowels_found)
    {
        cout << "No vowels found.";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you mean the following:)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    while ( true )
    {
        std::cout << "\nEnter some text (Enter - exit): ";

        std::string userString;

        if ( !std::getline( std::cin, userString ) || userString.empty() ) break;

        const char *vowels = "AaEeIiOoUu";

        bool present = false;

        for ( std::string::size_type pos = 0;
              ( pos = userString.find_first_of( vowels, pos ) ) != std::string::npos;
              ++pos )
        {
            if ( !present ) present = true;
            std::cout << userString[pos] << ' ';
        }

        if ( !present ) std::cout << "No vowels found.";

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }       

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter some text (Enter - exit): Hello World!
e o o 

Enter some text (Enter - exit): Hll Wrld!
No vowels found.

Enter some text (Enter - exit): hEllO wOrld!
E O O 

Enter some text (Enter - exit):
```

As for your code  then it does not make great sense.:)

For example in this declaration

```
char vowels = ('a','e','i','o','u');
```

there is used the comma operator and variable `vowels` will have value `'u'`.

Or this declaration

```
char stringArr = userString[0];
```

initializes `stringArr` with the terminating zero (provided that the code is compiled as C++ 2011)

Or the condition in the if statement

```
if (stringArr == 'a'|'e'|'i'|'o'|'u')
```

is always evaluates to `true` because at least `'e'` is not equal to 0.